# How to remove hover function from top row in table

Tags: html, css

I'm having trouble trying to remove the hover function I created from the top row in my table.

I'm trying to create a table that can be used to compare different products. I want to use a hover function for the whole table but the top row (where I will later put images). How can I remove the hover for top row only?

This is my code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Compare Table</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="index.css">
</head>
<body>

<table style="width:100%" class="hoverTable">
  <tr>
  <td class="blankcell"></td>
    <td id="check">Image</td>
    <td>Image</td> 
    <td>Image</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
   <td class="rowTitle">TITLE</td>
    <td>&#x2714</td>
    <td>&#x2714</td> 
    <td>&#x2714</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
  <td class="rowTitle">TITLE</td>
    <td id="check">&#x2714</td>
    <td>&#x2714</td> 
    <td>&#x2714</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
  <td class="rowTitle">TITLE</td>
    <td id="x01">&#x2716</td>
    <td>&#x2716</td> 
    <td>&#x2716</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
  <td class="rowTitle">TITLE</td>
    <td>&#x2714</td>
    <td>&#x2714</td> 
    <td>&#x2714</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

And the CSS:

```
th,td {
    padding: 15px;
    text-align: center;
}

.hoverTable tr:nth-child(even) {
    background-color: #eee;
}
.hoverTable tr:nth-child(odd) {
   background-color:#fff;
}

.blankcell {
    background: none!important; 
    border: none!important;
}


/* HOVER FUNCTION */
.hoverTable{
        width:100%; 
        border-collapse:collapse; 
    }
    .hoverTable td{ 
        padding:7px; 
        border: #000000 1px solid;
    }
    /* Define the default color for all the table rows */
    .hoverTable tr{
        background: #ffffff;
    }
    /* Define the hover highlight color for the table row */
    .hoverTable tr:hover {
          background-color: #86D694;
    }

/* Check and X-Mark Coloring*/
#check {
    color: #1CF200;
}
#x01 {
    color: #ff6969;
}
```

Thank you for your time!:)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
.hoverTable tr:not(:nth-child(1)):hover {
      background-color: #86D694;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/ebvywkg5/

Answer (score 4):

Try this:

```
.hoverTable tr:nth-child(n+2):hover {
      background-color: #86D694;
}
```

This only applies the hover to rows after the first row.

[DEMO](http://codepen.io/techsock/pen/jEZbvq)

Comment: I like this solution a lot. Note however, that depending on your requirements, IE 8 has limited [support](http://caniuse.com/#search=%3Anth-child) for _CSS3_ selectors like `:nth-child`. I know at this point, it's an older browser, but it's still worth consideration. Either way, +1

Answer (score 2):

You need to override the hovering style for the first row only. Add the below code:

```
.hoverTable tr:first-child:hover {
    background: #fff;
}
```

after this snippet:

```
/* Define the hover highlight color for the table row */
.hoverTable tr:hover {
      background-color: #86D694;
}
```

Below is a full live snippet that show's the results:

```css
th,td {
    padding: 15px;
    text-align: center;
}

.hoverTable tr:nth-child(even) {
    background-color: #eee;
}
.hoverTable tr:nth-child(odd) {
   background-color:#fff;
}

.blankcell {
    background: none!important; 
    border: none!important;
}


/* HOVER FUNCTION */
.hoverTable{
        width:100%; 
        border-collapse:collapse; 
    }
    .hoverTable td{ 
        padding:7px; 
        border: #000000 1px solid;
    }
    /* Define the default color for all the table rows */
    .hoverTable tr{
        background: #ffffff;
    }
    /* Define the hover highlight color for the table row */
    .hoverTable tr:hover {
          background-color: #86D694;
    }
    .hoverTable tr:first-child:hover {
        background: #fff;
    }

/* Check and X-Mark Coloring*/
#check {
    color: #1CF200;
}
#x01 {
    color: #ff6969;
}
```

```html
<table style="width:100%" class="hoverTable">
  <tr>
  <td class="blankcell"></td>
    <td id="check">Image</td>
    <td>Image</td> 
    <td>Image</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
   <td class="rowTitle">TITLE</td>
    <td>&#x2714</td>
    <td>&#x2714</td> 
    <td>&#x2714</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
  <td class="rowTitle">TITLE</td>
    <td id="check">&#x2714</td>
    <td>&#x2714</td> 
    <td>&#x2714</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
  <td class="rowTitle">TITLE</td>
    <td id="x01">&#x2716</td>
    <td>&#x2716</td> 
    <td>&#x2716</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
  <td class="rowTitle">TITLE</td>
    <td>&#x2714</td>
    <td>&#x2714</td> 
    <td>&#x2714</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Answer (score 1):

Add a "hov" class to all the table rows you want to be highlighted when hovered:

```
<table style="width:100%" class="hoverTable">
  <tr class="nohover">
  <td class="blankcell"></td>
    <td id="check">Image</td>
    <td>Image</td> 
    <td>Image</td>
  </tr>
  <tr class="hov">
   <td class="rowTitle">TITLE</td>
    <td>&#x2714</td>
    <td>&#x2714</td> 
    <td>&#x2714</td>
  </tr>
  <tr class="hov">
  <td class="rowTitle">TITLE</td>
    <td id="check">&#x2714</td>
    <td>&#x2714</td> 
    <td>&#x2714</td>
  </tr>
  <tr class="hov">
  <td class="rowTitle">TITLE</td>
    <td id="x01">&#x2716</td>
    <td>&#x2716</td> 
    <td>&#x2716</td>
  </tr>
  <tr class="hov">
  <td class="rowTitle">TITLE</td>
    <td>&#x2714</td>
    <td>&#x2714</td> 
    <td>&#x2714</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

And then change this CSS to include the "hov" class:

```
.hoverTable tr.hov:hover {
      background-color: #86D694;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's my recommendation that would simplify your question and make your table more accessible: put the first row in a `thead` tag and the remaining rows in a `tbody` tag. Then you can use the `tbody tr` selector to target the rows that aren't in the header.